# shiny R renderTable right alignment

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny R application in which I'm using "renderTable" function to render the table that is dynamically created.
The table may have 3 character columns and 4 numeric columns in one case and has 2 character columns and 2 numeric columns in another case.
The renderTable code from ui.R is :

```
     output$table1 <- renderTable({
                d1<-data()
             print(format(d1, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE,justify="right", nsmall=0))

     })
```

This is working for all format options specified except for justify. All numeric columns are left justified in the output.

Can anyone shed some light on why?

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap your `tableOutput` with an `uiOutput` (a.k.a. `htmlOutput`) in order to change the `align` parameter whenever the data changes. Here is an Example.

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table_wrapped = renderUI({
    # this table can be reactive since it is inside a render function
    reactiveTable = data.frame(
      name=sapply(1:input$nrows, function(x) paste(
        rep(letters[x], x), 
        collapse=''))
    )
    for( i in 1:input$ncols )
      reactiveTable[letters[i]] = seq(100, 100*input$nrows, by = 100)

    # calculate alignment vector (something like "lrrrrr")
    align = paste(rep('l', ncol(reactiveTable)))
    numeric_columns = which(as.logical(lapply(reactiveTable, is.numeric)))
    align[numeric_columns] = "r"
    align = paste(align, collapse ="")

    # create tableoutput. Since this is inside a render Function, 
    # the alignment changes with the inputs
    output$table <- renderTable({reactiveTable}, align = align)

    # return the tableOutput
    tableOutput('table')
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    sliderInput("ncols", "Number of numeric columns", 4, 10, 4),
    sliderInput("nrows", "Number of rows", 4, 10, 4)
  ),
  uiOutput('table_wrapped')
)

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the number of columns is always the same, you can use the `align` argument to `renderTable`, e.g.:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$tab <- renderTable({
        data.frame(a=seq(100, 1000, by=100), b=sapply(1:10, function(x) paste(rep(letters[x], x), collapse='')))
    }, align='rrr')

}

ui <- fluidPage(
    tableOutput('tab')
)

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Note that you have specify the alignment for the row names as well.

Comment: Matthew - The number of columns would be changing that is the challenge. Any other way to apply "align" for all numerical columns irrespective of number of columns?

Comment: This does not answer the question, the dynamic nature of the table makes this approach ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

if the number of columns varies but the desired alignment is the same you can use align = 'r'

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon [Gregor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44661674/415864), you can compute the `align` vector using the `compute_align()` function:

```
compute_align <- function(x, align = "l", except = NULL, rownames = NULL){
    align_vec <- rep(align, ncol(x))
    if(!is.null(except)){
        for(i in 1:length(except)){
            align_vec[ names(x) %in% except[[i]] ] <- names(except[i])
        }
    }
    if(!is.null(rownames)) align_vec <- c(rownames, align_vec)
    paste(align_vec, collapse = "")
}
```

- `align` - the default for all columns, one of `"l"`, `"c"` or `"r"`
- `except` - a named list, where the name is a valid value for `align` and the character vector for each element contains the names of the columns that will take that alignment
- `rownames` - if `rownames = TRUE` in `renderTable()`, this allows to specify the alignment of the row names. Accepts the same values as `align`.

Same example, implemented with this function. The function is probably applicable more generally to `xtable()` too.

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$table_wrapped = renderUI({
        # this table can be reactive since it is inside a render function
        reactiveTable = data.frame(
            name=sapply(1:input$nrows, function(x) paste(
                rep(letters[x], x), 
                collapse=''))
        )
        for( i in 1:input$ncols )
            reactiveTable[letters[i]] = seq(100, 100*input$nrows, by = 100)

        # calculate alignment vector (something like "lrrrrr")
        # create tableoutput. Since this is inside a render Function, 
        # the alignment changes with the inputs
        output$table <- renderTable({reactiveTable}, 
                                    align = compute_align(reactiveTable, align = "r", 
                                                          except = list(l=c("name"))))

        # return the tableOutput
        tableOutput('table')
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    inputPanel(
        sliderInput("ncols", "Number of numeric columns", 4, 10, 4),
        sliderInput("nrows", "Number of rows", 4, 10, 4)
    ),
    uiOutput('table_wrapped')
)

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this function work if I have my renderTable taking place outside a reactive statement?