# Reactive argument to render functions

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a table in a flexdashboard whose number of columns can change.  I can compute the alignment of the columns on the fly (default alignment treats `$23.45` as a character vector and thus left aligns the value though it is a number and should be right aligned).  The problem is I can't pass this alignment back to `renderTable` as a value to `align` because it's a reactive value.

How can I pass the reactive alignment back to the `renderTable` function's `align` argument? (or an alternative that let's me render a table with a reactive alignment)

## MWE

````
---
title: "test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput(
    "ncols", 
    label = "How many columns?",
    choices = 1:5, 
    selected = 5
)
```  

Column  
-------------------------------------

### Test

```{r}
nc <- reactive({input$ncols})
aln <- reactive({substring('lllrr', 1, nc())})

renderTable({
    x <- CO2[1:5, seq_len(nc()), drop = FALSE]
    x[, 1] <- as.character(x[, 1])
    x[3, 1] <- '<b>Mc1</b>'
    x
}, align = aln(), sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```
````

Results in:

```
 Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not 
 allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something 
 that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try wrapping `aln()` in `renderText(...)` i.e.

```
renderTable({
    x <- CO2[1:5, seq_len(nc()), drop = FALSE]
    x[, 1] <- as.character(x[, 1])
    x[3, 1] <- '<b>Mc1</b>'
    x
}, align = renderText(aln()), 
   sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

Comment: I loved this solution in that I knew I was using a reactive element incorrectly but didn't realize I could just use `renderText`.  Genius and generalizable to lots of situations.

Comment: I just want to add - **this only works because `renderTable` [accepts arguments that can be called as functions](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/v1.0.5/R/render-table.R#L69-L80)**. It is not generalizable to other render functions. This also means that neither `reactive` nor `renderText` are necessary, and you could pass in a function like `aln <- function() substring('lllrr', 1, nc())`, `renderTable(..., align = aln)`

Answer (score 6):

First things first, the specific error that occurred is quite correct. The function `renderTable` can only hold reactive expressions in its first argument `renderTable({ ... }, ...)`. All other things must be plain objects. So, putting a reactive value `aln()` there really was putting a `reactive` in a regular environment. Or, seen from the point of view of the `reactive` itself, it was evaluated *without an active reactive context* like it said in the error message.

A workaround to make those things reactive as well, is a wrapper around the `renderTable`, namely `renderUI`. Inside the `renderUI` we can reactively shape the whole table-rendering which includes the align. (Solution partly adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613803/shiny-r-rendertable-right-alignment).)

Here's what you have to replace the `renderTable` for:

```
renderUI({
  output$table <- renderTable({
      x <- CO2[1:5, seq_len(isolate(nc())), drop = FALSE]
      x[, 1] <- as.character(x[, 1])
      x[3, 1] <- '<b>Mc1</b>'
      x
  }, align = aln(), sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

  tableOutput("table")
})
```

**Quick explanation:** Using the `output` variable is like you would do it in a regular shiny environment, if not in markdown. What will be rendered by `renderUI` is then a reference to the `renderTable` which we will re-create from scratch every time.

**Note:** I used an `isolate` inside the `renderTable`. Here is why: `renderTable` is reactive and would update if `nc()` changes. But that can happen before the surrounding `renderUI` reacts to the change. You see, in this intermediate step, `renderTable` tries to plot a `data.frame` with a different column count, but the `align` is still the one from before. An error is thrown, because they don't match. Isolating the inner `nc()` stops the inner `renderTable` from updating. But that's okay, because the outer `renderUI` does this anyways once it is it's turn to update.

Comment: Thank you kindly for this solution.  It was very informative. +1