# Flexdashboard: Pass reactive value to chart-title

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

In the package flexdashboard the chart titles (headers for cells in the grid) are made via 3 hash marks (e.g., `### Chart title here`).  I want to pass a reactive value to this header.  Normally one could define a UI and push that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48118297/1000343) but the hash marks are what tell the knitting that this is a chart-title.  I also thought about passing the reactive value using in-line code (e.g., `` `r CODE HERE` ``) as seen in the MWE below.  You can use inline text for chart-titles but not when it contains reactive values.  This results in the error:

```
Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

In this case how could I pass the month in as a chart.title?

### MWE (removing last line allows this to run)

````
---
title: "test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput(
    "month", 
    label = "Pick a Month",
    choices = month.abb, 
    selected = month.abb[2]
)

getmonth <- reactive({
    input$month
})

renderText({getmonth()})
```  

Column  
-------------------------------------

### `r sprintf('Box 1 (%s)', month.abb[1])`


### `r sprintf('Box 2 (%s)', renderText({getmonth()}))`
````

Comment: I think this is gonna be tough without hacking up the chart title in raw HTML. I got *something* to work but it's real ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error that occurred was not part of `flexdashboard` being unable to render dynamic content but rather `sprintf` not being able to format the closure, that is `renderText`.

You only have to make the formatting part of your `reactive` and you're fine.

````
---
title: "test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput(
  "month", 
  label = "Pick a Month",
  choices = month.abb, 
  selected = month.abb[2]
)

getmonth <- reactive({
  sprintf('Box 2 (%s)', input$month)
})

renderText({getmonth()})
```  

Column  
-------------------------------------

### `r renderText(getmonth())`
````

Comment: Ahh, so this works with rmarkdown v1.7+ (https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/133). I was still running rmarkdown v1.6 and thought it was a flexdashboard specific issue.